# TypeScript reference other definitions within app - Duplicate Identifier error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gulp

Using Typescript with an Angular project.  At the top of each angular controller I often will have to reference other services so I need their definitions as well.  For example here is the top few lines of one controller that references a handful of services.

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../shared/checkoutstaticcontent.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../common/services/settingsservice.ts" />
/// <reference path="reviewcartservice.ts" />
```

I'm trying to add something to my gulp build process so that each controller only needs to reference a single .ts definition.

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

The tsd.d.ts file references angular, underscore, and other 3rd party library definitions.  I'd like for it to also reference a file myapp.d.ts which would contain all of my custom app definitions.  So I added the following gulp task to generate myapp.d.ts:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

gulp.src('Scripts/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(ts({ target: 'ES5', declaration: true }))
    .dts.pipe(concat('myapp.d.ts'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('typings'))
    .on('error', errorHandler);
```

This works great in creating the merged definition file.  The problem is that now I get an error that duplicate definitions are detected, because a file definition will exist by itself and also within the referenced myapp.d.ts.  What are my options for handling this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your typescript source files are present in the same project, and you are referencing the declaration ts files also in your Angular controller ts files, you are getting this issue.

A work around that I typically use is to create one reference.ts file that has references to all your custom code and refer to that reference.ts on top of your angular controller ts files. You wouldn't really need a declaration ts file in this case as you have the typescript source itself.

Declaration files can be used to share your definitions with other projects who will not have the actual typescript source at compile time but at run time the js files are merged together.

Comment: This is what I was initially going to do.  Was hoping there would be a way to update the master reference file without having to add everything manually.  Probably is a way to do this using gulp.  I'll try this out and see if it works, thanks.